Error configuring node-exporter DaemonSet scraping for Prometheus on kubernetes - service account token missing
I have set up a node-exporter DaemonSet on kubernetes as well as a service that points to these node-exporter pods IPs (I followed this tutorial). When I run kubectl get endpoints -n monitoring, I verify that the service is correctly pointing to the 3 DaemonSet pods that were created.
After that, inside the prometheus.yml file I have added this config for scraping the node-exporter metrics:
  - job_name: "node-exporter"
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
        namespaces:
          names:
          - monitoring
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
        regex: "node-exporter"
        action: keep

The problem is when I apply these configs and restart the prometheus.service:
> systemctl status prometheys.service --no-pager --full

● prometheus.service - PromServer
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-06-20 14:23:22 UTC; 12min ago
   Main PID: 1564211 (prometheus)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 33613)
     Memory: 43.6M
        CPU: 860ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/prometheus.service
             └─1564211 /usr/local/bin/prometheus --web.enable-admin-api --config.file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path /var/lib/prometheus/ --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries

Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.018Z caller=head.go:755 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=194 maxSegment=195
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.019Z caller=head.go:755 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=195 maxSegment=195
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.019Z caller=head.go:792 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL replay completed" checkpoint_replay_duration=6.863563ms wal_replay_duration=60.448333ms wbl_replay_duration=100ns total_replay_duration=69.694752ms
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.021Z caller=main.go:1040 level=info fs_type=EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.021Z caller=main.go:1043 level=info msg="TSDB started"
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.021Z caller=main.go:1224 level=info msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.025Z caller=manager.go:317 level=error component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes config=node-exporter
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.029Z caller=main.go:1261 level=info msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=7.816785ms db_storage=1.6µs remote_storage=1.3µs web_handler=400ns query_engine=901ns scrape=3.284277ms scrape_sd=295.907µs notify=67.202µs notify_sd=18.7µs rules=3.682588ms tracing=6.5µs
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.029Z caller=main.go:1004 level=info msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.029Z caller=manager.go:995 level=info component="rule manager" msg="Starting rule manager..."

I get this error specifically:

Jun 20 14:23:23 vm-devops-tiim-giro-prd prometheus[1564211]: ts=2024-06-20T14:23:23.025Z caller=manager.go:317 level=error component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes config=node-exporter

A colleague suggested I disable SSL to which I did, adding to the prometheus.yml this tls_config lines, under the node-exporter job:
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

But sadly it didn't solve it...
Why am I getting this error since I haven't got a service account configured in any config file related to the node-exporter? Also I've checked and this /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount directory doesn't even exist. What am I missing?
Note: this question has the same context as this one, but now I am getting a different error

Likely this doesn't have anything to do with Node exporter. Prometheus is trying to ask the Kubernetes API for the list of endpoints to discover the Node Exporter endpoints. It's trying to authenticate with the API server with the default service account, typically mounted at "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount".
That, mixed with the need to set the KUBERNETES_SERVICE_xx environment variables makes me think that things aren't being mounted correctly. What kind of k8s cluster are you using? Any special restrictions?
